# Understanding and creating the certificate request & Private Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, vps, linode

So I'm creating an RapidSSL on a Linode VPS for a Ruby on Rails - Spree Application.

I'm very new to SSL and in the documentation it's asking: to put in the name of your server where it says server.

**My Question:**
How do I figure out the server name of my VPS on Linode?

RapidSSL Documentation
https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO17540

Snippet:

*Login to your server via your terminal client (ssh). At the prompt, type:*

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

**where server is the name of your server.**
//end of snippet

Any other caveats to avoid would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your input's when creating the certificate says:

> Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:

And in the page you mentioned, you can read:

> Common Name (CN): The Common Name is the Host + Domain Name. It looks like "www.company.com" or "company.com".